# Text file to be only accessible from batch file and specific user

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that runs a script using a specific user's credentials being called from a text file. The problem is, anyone can follow the path and open said text file and see that user's sign-on credentials. I put them in stream files for added perplexity but by viewing the path in the batch file, anyone can figure it out.

*script.bat:*

```
@ECHO OFF

SET credentialsFile=.\SomeFile.txt:username.txt
SET anotherFile=.\SomeFile.txt:password.txt

SET /p username=<%credentialsFile%
SET /p password=<%anotherFile%

Script here that needs to use %username% and %password% for execution
```

This is being run on a server that several people have access to. What can be done to completely hide the contents of the text file from everyone but the batch file that calls it and the user who's credentials are being used?
Or another way of going about this instead of a text file?

**Note that this script is to run on startup and so the goal is to avoid requiring user input on execution in case the server were to go down in the middle of the night

Comment: Do you tag `powershell` because you want to have a PowerShell solution for it? Is it possible to convert the ability of the batch file into PowerShell? Then you can create a proper `PSCredential` object.

Comment: When I have access to the batch file, what hinders me to add `echo %username%,%password%`?

Comment: @Alex_P tagged powershell because I have a feeling it might be the best solution. Im researching PSCredential now, thanks

Comment: @Stephan Restrictions on the file itself can be changed to 'read-only' or the file can even be encrypted but the steam files would still be visible by using 'dir /R' from the command line

Comment: http://duffney.io/AddCredentialsToPowerShellFunctions , this is the best link I have found for `PSCredential` yet.

Comment: @AndrewM In batch, as long as I can read the source, I'll get the info. "Read-Only" is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that `PSCredential` objects may be a good solution for your use case.  To help you along, here is an example script that can store UserName and Password in `.txt` files and then use them to create a `PSCredential` object.

The Password is stored as a `SecureString` - unreadable if you simply open the .txt file.  The secure string is used to create the `PSCredentia`l object.  The `SecureString` can only be read by the same user account on the same machine that created it.

```
# This method will encrypt using the Windows Data Protection API, which 
# we are only able to access the password file with one account and only 
# on the same device that created the password file.

# Get the UserName and store it in a file
$UserName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter username for script" | Tee-Object "UserName.txt"

# Get the Password and store it as a secure string in a file
#  e.g. abc123
Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password for $Credential" -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "Password.txt"

# Get our password from the secure string we stored on disk
$Password = Get-Content "Password.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString

# Create a PS credential object using the username and password we've gathered
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName,$Password

# This yields the plain text password.  
#  e.g. abc123
$Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```